# How to check total call duration in ios 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

In call log list there is option to check duration of each call. is there is any option to check total call duration of my iphone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work with iOS 7 and above.

- Go to the **Settings** app and tap the **Cellular** icon at the bottom of the screen.

Anything beyond that, you will have to check your phone bill.

[image: Call Log]

Comment: I was looking for total call duration. Not individual. Thanks

Comment: @tollin total call duration for each number called? What is shown here is not individual calls but all calls ever made / all calls made after the last reset of the counter.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can see this by clicking:

- Settings
- Cellular
- You can see total duration on this page including since last reset

Comment: no Cellular option found in settings

Comment: Who is your carrier?  Are you in US or other country?  The Cellular is right there in Settings grouped with Airplane Mode and Bluetooth.  At least on all of my devices.